# Sanitizing URL to prevent XSS in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xss

In an rails application, users can create events and post an url to link to the external event site.

How do I sanitize the urls to prevent XSS links?

Thanks in advance,

example of XSS, which is not preventable by rails' sanitize method

```
@url = "javascript:alert('XSS')"
<a href="<%=sanitize @url%>">test link</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try sanitizing once the href is already in a tag like:

```
url = "javascript:alert('XSS')"
sanitize link_to('xss link', url)
```

This gives me:

```
<a>xss link</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Rails' [sanitize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html) method for some basic restriction.

Or you can use rgrove's [sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize) gem for more options.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @url = "javascript:alert('XSS')" <a href="<%=sanitize @url%>">xss link</a> does not work. i should reflect in my question that i have already tested the rails' sanitize method.

Comment: rgrove's sanitize gem is really nice if you need more control than the built-in Rails sanitize gives you. Either way, like Ben's answer points out, you need to sanitize the html for the entire link, not just the URL itself.

Answer (score 2):

`sanitize` works with html strings, not urls. meaning, you can't sanitize an URL itself, but you can sanitize a piece of html which has a link with an malicious url. for example

```
<%= sanitize "<a href='#{@url}'>Things</a>" %>
```

That will clean your link of all known malicious attributes

Answer (score -2):

This vulnerability has been fixed since 3.2.13, 3.1.12, 2.3.18 .

The following link also provides a patch you can use in earlier versions.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rubyonrails-security/zAAU7vGTPvI/1vZDWXqBuXgJ